# Internet Explorer not displaying gif file

Tags: html, gif

My friend is making a website. Some of the pages display gif image files as links. They display correctly in Firefox and Chrome but not in Internet Explorer. How can I get the images to display in Internet Explorer? Here is a line of html code that should display the gif links:

```
<a href="kendo.htm"><img src="arrowprev.gif" alt="previous page arrow"/></a>
  | <a href="index.htm">HOME</a> 
  | <a href="festivals.htm"><img src="arrownext.gif" alt="next page arrow"/></a>
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Do all other images display correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .gif files being used are simply not compatible with Internet Explorer 8. I am not sure why though since IE 8 does support .gif files. When I try to open the .gif file itself directly with IE8, it does not display. IE8 can directly open and display other .gif files though.

Comment: One solution for this is open the image using an image manipulation program such as GIMP and re saving it.

Answer (score 1):

Try these two links:

- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/283807
- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307239

Answer (score 0):

Chances are that the colorspace for those images is CMYK, not RGB.  Is he a graphic designer who is more at home in print than the web?